# How to avoid ovewriting data in entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I do have question abount how jpa is working, and how can avoid one of situation which bother me.

Ok so let me start with simple snippet.

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Employee> index() {
        Employee employee1 = employeeRepository.findById(1L).get();
        Employee employee2 = ovewrite(employee1);
        Employee employee3 = employeeRepository.findById(1L).get();

        return Arrays.asList(employee1, employee2, employee3);
    }

    private Employee ovewrite(Employee employee){
        employee.setFirstName("Test");
        return employee;
    }
```

As you can see, I created some code to test what will happens with employee found with `id == 1`.
I did get `employee1` from db, passed it to `ovewrite` method which just change `firstName` and after that I did get from db the same employee.

And what I dont understand here is that employee3 has name changes even if there was no commits to database with this change. I suppose jpa is caching this data and with each new `find` to this object we are getting modified record?

And another question, how could I avoid this situation? Because I do have one project with this kind of 'bug'. And for me easiest way to fix it would be just to disallow this kid of sinchronization.

[EDIT]
So I tried to avoid this caching 'issue', by calling `find` inside of new transaction. But still, my employee3 has changed name properties.

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public List<Employee> index() {
        Employee employee1 = employeeRepository.findById(1L).get();
        ovewrite(employee1);
        Employee employee3 = newTxFind();
        return Arrays.asList(employee1, employee3);
    }


    private Employee ovewrite(Employee employee){
        employee.setFirstName("Test");
        return employee;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Employee newTxFind(){
        return employeeRepository.findById(1L).get();
    }
```

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- Is method `index` by any chance annotated with `@Transactional`?

Comment: @Turing85 nope, what you see in my code snippet was run as it is pasted here

Comment: Then it might - in fact - be due to caching. Could you check the value of `employee2 == employee3`?

Comment: AFAIK Spring Boot uses a concept called "Open Session In View" (OSIV). This opens a Hibernate session for a controller request and closes it after that request is done. Therefore Hibernate caching is most probably in place for both calls `employeeRepository.findById(1L)`. See, if disabling OSIV (`spring.jpa.open-in-view = false`) changes the behaviour. (I am not really sure ...)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose is right, just looked it up. `open-in-view` is activated by default (see [this article over at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view) for details). This means that the entity fetched from database is still attached to the transactional context. This, in return, means that changes to the entity are automatically committed to the database. To prevent this behaviour we have two general options: execute fetching in another transaction or explicitly detach the entity through the entity manager.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the emplyee1 and employee3 will be the same object and this has to do with JPA cache. All JPA implementations have at least Level 1 cache, i.e. session/transaction cache. You can confirm this by:

```
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(employee1));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(employee3));
```

Note that the object returned by findById(1L) is "the same" only for the current JPA Transaction. If the same findById(1L) is executed from another thread at the same time, in parallel, then the output of findById(1L) will be a different object. Same will be true (you will receive a different object) if for some reason you call findById(1L) from within a method annotated by

```
@javax.transaction.Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)
```

or by

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation = Propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
```

If you want to avoid changing the database when modifying the employee1 object you can detach it from the session, if this is you really need. A detached object can later be re-attached but there are caveats and most likely there is a better workaround.

Comment: I tried calling `find` in new tx. But it seems I am still getting the same result. I pasted code in first post.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of calling jpa query multiple times.Its better to create a empty instance for Employee object and copy the whole original data into it before call overwrite function.after all the process you should have original data and override data as well.

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public List < Employee > index() {
        Employee employee3 = new Employee();
        Employee employee1 = employeeRepository.findById(1 L).get();
        //apache common library you may find it other alternatives too
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(employee3, employee1):
        ovewrite(employee1);
        return Arrays.asList(employee1, employee3);
    }

    private Employee ovewrite(Employee employee) {
        employee.setFirstName("Test");
        return employee;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

When you write

```
Thing thing2 = thing1;
```

it does not create a new thing. You have exactly one thing.  Thus your variables employee1 and employee2 refer to the same Employee.

Comment: OP talks about `employee3`, not `employee2`.

Comment: I should not introduce `employee2`, my bad

Comment: Ah, I see. I supposed this was the common misunderstanding of reference semantics.